# Having trouble with this loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I was wondering if there is a way where this loop will keep looping if i do not answer yes or no. Say I answer pizza i want it to say "Answer provided does not pertain to the question please answer yes or no.".

```
ques1 = input('\nHas new information been aquired for this person?_ ').lower()
    
if  ques1 == 'yes':
    key = input('What information has been found ex. "Job,weight,height":')
    value = input('what is the new or added update:')    
else:
    print('\nIts important to report all new changes to keep profile up to date!')
    time.sleep(2)    
    new_search = input('\nWould you like to search for someone else? yes or no: ')
    if new_search == 'yes':
                    main()
    else:  
        print('\nGoodbye')
        exit()
```

Comment: there is no while loop

Comment: To add to @drops comment you will need to use the `while` keyword. If you research that you will be on the right track.

Comment: @HoneyPoop yes that is my question.

Comment: You can put `while True:` condition and put your entire code inside that.